# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.0.0

Tags: tensorflow, pip, version, distribution, matching

*I have below version of python*:
    C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe

*and executed the command*:
    pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow

*getting the following error*:

Collecting tensorflow==1.0.0

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.0.0 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.0.0

A solution of this issue will be appreciated
Thanks :)

Comment: you might consider upgrading your pip version.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing Anaconda 4.2.0 and then re-try.
Additionally, if you want some feature of tf1, you can disable the v2 compatibility and enable v1:

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not installing the latest version 1.3.0 with `sudo pip3 install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.3.0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl`?

Comment: i tried installing the above version too but still got the same error

Comment: Is tensorflow available for 32-bit windows system??

Comment: Sorry, no idea.

Comment: @AvinashPatel There are no official prebuilt binaries for TensorFlow on any 32-bit platform. You can try [building from sources](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/cmake/README.md).